# Переопределение метода __isub__() в python

Tags: python, list

Разбираюсь как переопределять методы класса.

Задача: из списка вычесть список.

Т.к. значения в списках могут быть разных типов, пошел путем создания нового списка из строчных значений и кучи проверок.

Ошибка на c1.

Помогите разобраться
`obj -= list` : работает
`list -= obj` : не работает

Запутался, закомментировал все и пошел сюда...

```
class SubN:
    def __init__(self, l: list):
        self.__l = l

    def get_list(self):
        return self.__l

    # noinspection PyArgumentList
    def check(self, value) -> list:
        if isinstance(value, SubN):
            return value.get_list()
        return value

    def convert(self, other):
        if type(other) == list:
            return list(map(str, other))
        elif type(other) == SubN:
            return list(map(str, other.get_list()))

    def convert_rev(self, other):
        # вернуть значения к своим типам...
        return other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        # print()
        # print('.__sub__')
        # print(f'Удаляем из списка {self.get_list()} значения списка {self.check(other)}\n')

        other = self.convert(other)
        output = self.convert(self.get_list())

        for i in other:
            # print(f'Ищем и удаляем из списка: {i}')
            if i not in output:
                # print(f'{i} в списке отсутствует. Далее\n')
                continue
            else:
                # print(f'{i} - удалено..')
                del output[output.index(i)]
        return  self.convert_rev(output)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        if type(other) == list:
            return SubN(other) - self.get_list()
        return other - self

    # def __isub__(self, other):
    #     if type(other) == SubN:
    #         x = SubN(other)
    #         x -= self
    #         return x



if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_l = [2, 13, 0, -9.5, 1, 'String', False, 0, True]
    test_2 = [2, False, -9, True, 9]
    test_3 = [-9, -6]

    a = SubN(test_l)
    b = SubN(test_2)

    ## OK
    res_1 = a - [2, False, -9, True, 9]
    print(f'1. sub ->  {res_1}') # [13, 0, -9.5, 1, 'String',0]

    ## OK
    res_2 = test_2 - a
    print(f'2. rsub -> {res_2}') #  [-9, 9]

    ## OK
    res_3 = a - b
    print(f'3. obj - obj -> {res_3}') # [13, 0, -9.5, 1, 'String',0]

    ## - OK
    res_4 = b - a
    print(f'4. obj - obj -> {res_4}') # [-9, 9]

    ##
    c = SubN([-9, 9, 8, 8, -6, 6])
    c1 = [-9, 9, 8, 8, -6, 6]

    c -= test_3
    print(f'5. isub -> {c}') # [9,8,8,6]
    c1 -= test_3
    print(f'5. isub -> {c1}') # [9,8,8,6]
```

Comment: Если вы про ошибку `c1 -= test_3 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'list'`, то ничего удивительного. Вы от стандартного списка отнимаете стандартный список, а в нем операция -= не определена. Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы ожидали от строчки `c1 -= test_3`.

Comment: что бы правильно из листа "вычелся" лист..)

Comment: правильно - это как?

Comment: [-9, 9, 8, 8, -6, 6] - [-9, -6] = [9, 8, 8, 6]

Comment: я понимаю что мне надо переопределить методы __isub__ (он закомментированный у меня).. не могу сообразить как...

Comment: Переопределить метод вы можете в потомке списка, а вы проводите операцию с объектами стандартного списка.

Comment: по-русски это не "лист", а "список".